# SQL Case statement for impala

Tags: sql

I have below requirement in Impala, can someone please help me on this.

if table1.column1 is null or empty string ,then table1.column2 else concat(table1.column1," ",table1.column2) as address

```
select 
**the above condition** 
from table1.
```

Comment: ...and none of the answers given will run on all those dbms's.

Comment: I've just gone ahead and removed the tag spam. [Edit] your question and tag properly please.

Comment: sorry for that...i use impala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    Select case when  column1 is null or column1='' 
     then 
     column2 else concat(column1," ",column2) end as 
      address from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Simple `ISNULL`. You don't need a case here

```
SELECT
    Address = LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(Column1+' ','')+ISNULL(Column1,'')))
    FROM YourTable
```